# Error 403 with Twitters streaming API while sending a POST request - C#

Tags: c#, twitter-oauth, twitter-streaming-api

I'm building an bot that auto replies to tweets that contain specific words. I am using HttpWebRequest to make a request to the streaming API and posting the tweet. Only problem is that the twitter API limits the ammount of requests you can make in a specific ammount of time. This makes the stream request successful but the request to post a tweet fails with the 403 error. How can i avoid this? (Not really sure if this is actually the problem, but it seems so.)

I used this as an layout on how the stream request thingy works http://www.emoticode.net/c-sharp/twitter-stream-api-client-example.html

If you know anything about this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Twitter docs([error codes](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes), [limits](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following)) you should get an error message explaining what limit you hit (if you hit it). That should clarify if that is truly your problem.

If it is I suggest using a message queue or a response schedule, to allow you to track how many tweets you are sending. Maybe you could also assign priorities to those tweets you want to respond to, even filter out some low priority ones eventually. That depends really on the load of tweets you will be processing.